# face_recognition can't assign to function call

Tags: python, face-recognition

I'm trying to make a universal code that trains anybody it sees.
I'm trying to use a variable to add to it every time a see someone new, but it gives this error:

> SyntaxError
>   can't assign to function call

I'm using the face_recognition library like this

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
first_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("photo0")
first_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encoding(first_image)[0]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
count = 0
count +"encoding" = face_recognition.load_image_file("photo0")
count +"_face_encoding" = face_recognition.face_encodings(first_image)[0]
count += 1
```

Comment: You can't create new variables with string concatenation

Comment: Images that convey only text should be replaced by the text itself. Images of text are not searchable, not accessible, and are hard to read on small screens.

Comment: There is an exercise pretty much exactly like this out of the book "BlackHat Python" which I think would help you resolve this question.  It is used for Facial recognition.